# How would I call a constructor of an abstract class inside of an extending class constructor

Tags: java, class, constructor, abstract, extends

So for my homework I have to create an abstract class that has a few extending classes. I am stuck at one part. I can't seem to find anywhere in my lesson that tells me how to call a constructor of an abstract class. This is my teachers instructions.

```
MyMath's constructor will just call Homework's constructor and again have no arguments.
```

This is my code that I have for the abstract constructor:

```
public Homework(){
    pagesRead = 0;
    typeHomework = "none";
}
```

and in MyMath class I am supposed to call this constructor inside of the constructor for MyMath, I'm not sure how to do this and I cant find it in any other lessons we have been over. Any help is appreciated :)

Comment: by calling the constructor of the child class, how else? calling the subconstructor will automatically call the parent constructor, even if you don't write the code explicitly

Comment: you call a superclass constructor with `super()` as the first line in your subclass constructor. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/super.html

Comment: You call the abstract class's constructor just like you do any other superclass constructor: Either implicitly (only if it doesn't require arguments), or via `super(/*...*/)` as @JackFlamp mentioned, either to be explicit or to pass arguments to it. Odd for an abstract class to have a `public` constructor, though (as opposed to `protected`), though I suppose it doesn't make any difference...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [Stultuske](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2636929/stultuske) already said, the super class constructor will automatically called when you create a subclass object. Alternate, you can call it explicitly by *super()*. Moreover, if your super class don't have a default constructor you must call it also explicitly.

```
public abstract class Homework
{
  public Homework(int i)
  {
    ...
  }
}

public class MyClass extends Homework
{
  public MyClass()
  {
    super(5);
  }
}
```

Comment: *"Moreover, if your super class don't have a default constructor you must call it also explicitly."* Not quite. If the superclass doesn't have a *zero-parameters* constructor, you must call it explicitly. It doesn't have to be a default constructor, and frequently may not be. (The default constructor is a zero-params constructor, but not all zero-params constructors are default constructors -- some are explicitly-provided.)